# Nvidia X Server Settings does not allow me to apply changes

Tags: drivers, nvidia-settings

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, Nvidia X server settings no longer allows me to configure for a second display (a projector).  The two displays are detected just fine, and I change the resolution in both so that they match, and configure them as clones. Then I hit "apply" and the program just quits without changing anything. I redo everything and hit "Save to X configuration file" but the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is unchanged, although the file is written with a new write date.

Here is the output in the terminal:

```
(nvidia-settings:3437): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/schultz/.config/ibus/bus is not root! 
The program 'nvidia-settings' received an X Window System error. 
This probably reflects a bug in the program. 
The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'. 
(Details: serial 847 error_code 2 request_code 157 minor_code 25) 
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously; that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it. To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Through all this, the projector does display my desktop, but only a region to the right of the boundary of my monitor, which I'm not able to access with the mouse.

I realize similar questions have been asked before, but they have not yet been answered.  Also, there is a bug report, but I'm wondering if there's a simple workaround, maybe some way of manually entering the configuration changes, so at least I can create some different xorg.conf files for different lecture rooms/projectors and reboot the laptop with those, before lecturing.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by installing the latest nvidia Unix driver following [the instructions here](http://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/ubuntu-nvidia-projector-screen-cloning-1024x768-resolution/)

I downloaded the driver from [nvidia.com here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html)

The driver version I installed is 304.123 for Linux x86_64/AMD64/EM64T.

The driver now sitting in the repository, nvidia-current, is not the latest driver, and appears to be the cause of the problem.